# Compile Errors in Class with User Defined Functions

Tags: class, boost, functor

I am trying to build a class that stores a user-defined function inside of it for later use. I have decided to use the `boost::function` object to do so.

However, I get the following error on compile:

`error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((SomeClass*)this)->SomeClass::someFunction = ((SomeClass*)this)->SomeClass::DefaultFunction’`

I do not understand this error, since someFunction and DefaultFunction should, as far as I can see, have the same types.

The code is shown below:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class SomeClass{
    private:
            boost::function<int(int)> someFunction;
            int DefaultFunction(int i);

    public:
            SomeClass();
            ~SomeClass();
            void SetFunction(int (*f)(int));
    };

int SomeClass::DefaultFunction(int i){
    return i+1;

}

SomeClass::SomeClass(){
    someFunction=DefaultFunction;
}

~SomeClass::SomeClass(){

 }

 void SomeClass::SetFunction(int (*f)(int i)){
        someFunction=f;
 }

 void MyProgram(){
        SomeClass s;
 }
```

Can anyone offer any pointers as to how to construct such an object? Alternatively, iff there is a better way than the one I am attempting, could you explain it to me?

Kindest regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultFunction` is a member function of `SomeClass`.
Member function is called for some instance of `SomeClass`.
This function takes "hidden" pointer to `SomeClass` instance as its first parameter addition to `int`.
So member function is not the same as free function.

Your `someFunction` is object of `boost::function`, so it is wrapper for callable object.
Your requirements to that object are: take int and returns int.
In order to assign `DefaultFunction` (as member function) to `someFunction` you need to create this callable object.
Here you need to specify for which instance of `SomeClass` this object will be called, to do that use `boost::bind`:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(){
    someFunction=boost::bind(&SomeClass::DefaultFunction, this, boost::placeholders::_1);
}
```

In the code above you create callable object which will behave as

```
struct unnamedClass {
    SomeClass* sc;
    unnamedClass (SomeClass* sc) : sc(sc) {} // here sc is this of SomeClass

    int operator()(int arg)
    {
        return sc->DefaultFunction(arg);
    }
};
```

so when you invoke `someFunction(10)` it takes 10 as argument and call `DefaultFunction` for current `this` instance.

This

```
void SomeClass::SetFunction(int (*f)(int i)){
    someFunction=f;
 }
```

works because `f` is free function, which takes no hidden - pointer to class instance.

Comment: Fantastic answer! However, I get a compile error. I have added:

`#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>`

Yet I get the error:

`error: ‘placeholders’ is not a member of ‘boost’ `

Can you provide any clarity on this?

Comment: @JackRolph [Under this link](https://godbolt.org/z/t2HtMp) you have full compiled version, try this. You had a typo in destructor.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code from the link I attached, and test again? You added `boost/bind/placeholders.hpp` so it should work.

Comment: I copied and pasted ad verbatim. The error persists: `MyClass.C:22: error: ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared`. Is this a problem with Boost?

Comment: I am using g++ to compile: 
 `g++ MyProgram.C -lboost_system`

I have checked and the header is installed under `/usr/include/boost/bind/placeholders.hpp`

Comment: Why did you save your file with `.C` extension, instead of `.cpp` ?  It is for C-compiler.

Comment: Because the ROOT software package that I am using for the main program uses a C-Compiler - it is common convention, at least in my experience, for macros to use .C. You are right though, in this case it can be .cpp. It is just convention I have picked up! :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of @rafix07, the following code compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/placeholders.hpp>

class SomeClass{
private:

public:
        SomeClass();
        ~SomeClass();
        boost::function<int(int)> someFunction;
        int DefaultFunction(int i);
        void SetFunction(int (*f)(int));
};

int SomeClass::DefaultFunction(int i){
     return i+1;
 }

SomeClass::SomeClass(){ 
someFunction=boost::bind(&SomeClass::DefaultFunction, this, _1);

}

SomeClass::~SomeClass(){
}

void SomeClass::SetFunction(int (*f)(int i)){
   someFunction=f;
}

int MyOwnProgram(int i){
    return i+2;
}

void MyProgram(){
    SomeClass s;
    std::cout<<s.someFunction(2)<<std::endl;
    s.SetFunction(MyOwnProgram);
    std::cout<<s.someFunction(2)<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyProgram();
}
```

The output from the program is:

```
3
4
```